# How can this be expressed as a MILP constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, constraint, binary-variable

I am looking for a constraint to express the following:

IF W1 = 0 AND W2 = 0 THEN Y = 1  
IF W1 = 0 AND W2 = 1 THEN Y = 1 
IF W1 = 1 AND W2 = 0 THEN Y = 0 
IF W1 = 1 AND W2 = 1 THEN Y <= 1

Variables W1, W2, Y are binaries. 
Y is determined by the aforementioned relations. 
So, I am looking for an expression Y(W1,W2) =  ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work :

\begin{align*}
1-\omega_1 &\le y \\
\omega_1 - \omega_2 &\le 1- y
\end{align*}

- If $\omega_1 = 0$ and $\omega_2 \in \{0,1\}$, then the equations hold only if $y = 1$
- If $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2 = 0$, then the equations hold only if  $y = 0$
- If $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2 = 1$, then the equations hold if  $y \in \{ 0,1\}$

Answer (score 3):

@Kuifje’s answer is correct. Here’s how you can obtain the constraints via conjunctive normal form. The first two propositions can be combined, and the fourth proposition is a tautology, so we want to enforce
$$(\neg W_1\implies Y)\land ((W_1\land \neg W_2)\implies\neg Y).$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$
(W_1\lor Y)\land ((\neg W_1\lor W_2)\lor\neg Y)\\
(W_1+Y\ge 1)\land (1-W_1+W_2+1-Y\ge 1)\\
(Y\ge 1-W_1)\land (1-Y\ge W_1-W_2).
$$

Comment: Kuifje's answer is indeed correct.
Can you give the answer to the same setting but this time the first preposition reads: 
if W1 = 0 and W2 = 0 the Y = 0 ?

Comment: Please open a new question for that to avoid confusion.